voiceover's focus shifts to the text label but does not get read
While trying to create pdf forms from third party service (formio) accessible, I ran into this weird issue, where when a user steps into the iframe labelled as "iframe 2" the voiceover's focus shifts to the text label "BIO Data" but it does not get read by the voiceover. 
The iframe has been added using inline iframe, I have also attached a codepenio demo :
<iframe class="interactive is-tabbed-standard-height" width="900" height="500" src="https://pro.formview.io/#/eaalrbwfwiweuge/dummyform?header=1&reset=1" title="some pdf form created using formio " allow="clipboard-write" loading="lazy"></iframe>

As a consequence, user has to again press ctrl + option + right arrow in order to make voiceover read the text label. Can anybody please help why isn't voiceover automatically reading out the text label when it gets focused.
Note : This does not occur while using NVDA on windows.
Attachments :
[1] video demo link : https://streamable.com/m40v9f?src=player-page-share 
[2] codepenio link : https://codepen.io/anyonesomewhere/pen/jORdPyj

@KJ strange, are you using Voiceover on mac ? And did you go through the video for reference ?

aah I see edge blocking the iframe content. Can you try it somehow on a mac (if available) because it's a voiceover issue particularly

Is it on Mac or on iOS? Apparently the demo is outdated, the mentioned label does not exist any more. Would it be possible to reproduce the code that causes it? Until then, I vote to close the issue.

hey @Andy I will revert back to you in a short while. Thnx for showing interest into this issue. And it's basically occurring on mac (only chrome not safari)
